# Synchronizing 2 threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am having great difficulty in synchronising 2 Threads. Each thread depends on the results of the other thread. Let's say I have the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Condition, Process
import time

def B_producer(new_A,new_B):
    while True:
        with new_A:
            new_A.wait()

        with new_B:
            print 'B',
            new_B.notify_all()


if __name__=='__main__':
    new_A = Condition()
    new_B = Condition()

    B_producer = Process(target=B_producer, args=(new_A,new_B))
    B_producer.start()

    time.sleep(2)

    while True:
        with new_A:
            print 'A',
            new_A.notify()


        with new_B:
            new_B.wait()
```

What I would like to see is an output like: A B A B A B A B A B..., so that the main thread starts by generating an 'A', while the other is waiting. Once an 'A' has been produced, it waits for the 'B'. Meanwhile, the secondary thread do the opposite. There can be no repetition of letters. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to make it work as expected.

EDIT: Given the discussion in the first answer, I altered the code in order to make it more clear that the program enters in a deadlock and never terminates:

```
from multiprocessing import Condition, Process
import time

def B_producer(new_A,new_B):
    while True:
        with new_A:
            new_A.wait()

        with new_B:
            #do something
            new_B.notify_all()


if __name__=='__main__':
    new_A = Condition()
    new_B = Condition()

    B_producer = Process(target=B_producer, args=(new_A,new_B))
    B_producer.start()

    time.sleep(2)

    count = 0

    while True:
        with new_A:
            #do something
            new_A.notify()


        with new_B:
            new_B.wait()

        count += 1
        if count == 1000000:
            break

    B_producer.terminate()
    sys.stdout.write('end')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got a solution for it, even though there may be a simpler one. I added a start condition to it in order to avoid the main loop from starting before the B_producer is ready and waiting for the main thread to do its part. I also had to add an additional Lock to prevent a race condition to the new_A condition.

```
def B_producer(new_A,new_B,synch,start):
    synch.acquire()
    while True:
        with new_A:
            synch.release()
            with start:
                start.notify()
            new_A.wait()

            with new_B:

                #Do something

                synch.acquire()
                new_B.notify()

if __name__=='__main__':
    new_A = Condition()
    new_B = Condition()
    start = Condition()
    synch = Lock()

    B_producer = Process(target=B_producer, args=(new_A,new_B,synch,start))
    with start:
        B_producer.start()
        start.wait()

    count = 0

    synch.acquire()

    while True:
        new_A.acquire()
        synch.release()

        #Do something

        with new_B:
            new_A.notify()
            new_A.release()

            new_B.wait()
            synch.acquire()

        count += 1
        if count%100000 == 0:
            break

    B_producer.terminate()
    print 'end'
```

If anybody finds a better/simpler solution, please post it!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your code works, the only thing is you experience some issues with `print "A/B",`. The problem here is the comma after `print`. It prevents a line break after printing but the print statement is not able to update an already written line on the console but only to write single lines. Therefore it stores everything in a buffer until you perform a `print` **with** linebreak and then the whole line is written.

You can do two things:

- Remove the comma after `print` (which will cause every letter to be printed in a separate line).
- Or if you wish to write them to the same line you can use `sys.stdout.write('A/B ')` followed by `sys.stdout.flush()` (to keep the output updated). Don't forget to `import sys`.

Comment: The modification shows that there was a problem with the print, but the program still enters in a deadlock after some iterations.

Comment: I think that's because it's just too much to display for the computer in too little time so it just stops. If you put a `time.sleep(0.01)` after `print` or `sys.stdout.flush()` it'll run forever.

Comment: I wish you were also right this time, but, instead of printing 'A' or 'B', use a counter on the main thread and increase it at each loop. When the count value reaches 10000 for example, break the loop and print something. It will still enter in deadlock never coming out of the loop.

Comment: If you want to quit your program you should of course call `B_producer.terminate()` when it's finished (as you started the process before). A process which was started also has to be terminated when the job is done. I.e. you need a `B_producer.terminate()` before the break. Otherwise the process will keep on running and your program itself won't terminate.